# schedule Azure machine learning compute instances

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-vm

I want to schedule azure machine learning compute instances so that I can stop them during off-hours like weekends, azure automation solution with runbook seems to be working with VMs in general but not with azure ML. The solution could be either a script or ML pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like since today you can specify schedule during compute instance creation or just edit already existing compute instance and add a schedule for it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compute instance is a PaaS service where resources are hosted in Azure ML subscription. As compute instances replaced Notebook VM,you are no longer able to see VM after creating Compute instance.

Auto-shutdown based on schedule/utilization is on the roadmap for compute instance.

Currently you can stop/start compute instance using SDK/API making automation possible.

Comment: As this os over one year old, how's the progress?

Comment: @AndiAnderle see my reply, it is available now